# JMeter Threads Finishing Before They Should

Tags: multithreading, jmeter, timeout, performance-testing

I have a thread group which seems to finish threads before they should be.

Each thread makes 1 request, then hits an inifinite loop (containing 1 request), which includes a timer within this samplerof just under an hour.

I've tried splitting this timer out into 4 individual constant timer incase it didnt like such a high value, but didnt seem to work.

My ramp up is for 1000 users over a period of an hour, and then hold for 10 mins.

It finishes threads at the same point each time, only ever reaching 320. Which takes approx 16 mins. Or exactly 1000000 milliseconds.

Does anyone know if theres a timeout value of 1000000ms whereby if a thread hasn't made a request it is terminated?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just seen for Stepping Thread Group:

"This plugin is deprecated and should not be used. Use Concurrency Thread Group instead."

I was using Stepping Thread Group.

I have rerun my test using Concurrency Thread Group and all runs as it should.